# getElementsbyClassName not working as desired

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, onclick

I am having a little problem while trying to use the 'getElementsByClassName' tag. I am using it to trigger the Facebook Share Box when somebody clicks on any element which has the class 'fb' assigned to it but the Facebook Share Box only pops up when you click on the first element with the 'fb' class but it doesn't work for other elements with the 'fb' class. The code which I am using is listed below.

JS:

> ```
> window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
>         FB.init({
>           appId      : 'xxx',
>           xfbml      : true,
>           version    : 'v2.0'
>         });
> document.getElementsByClassName('fb')[0].onclick = function() {
>   FB.ui({
>     display: 'popup',
>     method: 'share',
>       href: 'http://allwebutilities.com/ik/medals/air-force-meritorious-civilian-service-medal/',
>   }, function(response){});
> }
>       };
>
>       (function(d, s, id){
>          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
>          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
>          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
>          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
>          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
>        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
> ```

HTML:

```
<a id="facebook" href="#" class="fb">Facebook</a>

<a id="facebook" href="#" class="fb">Facebook</a>

<a id="facebook" href="#" class="fb">Facebook</a>
```

An example showcasing my problem can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/yt0hj6w3/1/. The Facebook Share Box only pops up when you click on the first 'Facebook' link but not for second or third link.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are referring only to first link

```
document.getElementsByClassName('fb')[0]
```

`[0]` at the end means that will be applied only to first element that found, to apply to all elements you should

```
var fb = document.getElementsByClassName('fb');
for (var i = 0; i < fb.length; i++) {
    fb[i].onclick = ...
}
```